# How to integrate paypal payments with drupal 6?

Tags: drupal, paypal, payment

I've been looking through paypal modules for D6 and I'm a little confused. I am building a website where people will pay for courses (using paypal). Is there a simple module that I can use to do this, or will I need to use Ubercart which will be overkill?

My programming skills are limited...

Ben

Comment: Hi Kevin, I didn't realise I needed to accept answers. I have gone through all my questions and accepted the answers that helped. I noticed I could only accept one answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a bunch of options for paypal:

http://drupal.org/search/apachesolr_search/paypal?filters=type:project_project

Ubercart is good too. You might find yourself needing more advance features later on, and you wouldn't have to reconfigure all over again if you simply start with Ubercart.

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your answer. I did look quite hard yesterday at the available modules in Drupal. It seemed like some of the simplest solutions were for Drupal 4 and 5. I think ubercart will probably be my best option.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend on ubercart.
I have just finish setting up Ubercart with Paypal WPS (on the paypal sandbox), and when you know what to do, it is a great solution.
From my experience, you can never tell what would be the enhancement you will need in the future. This is why I love Drupal's modularity and scaleability, as well as Ubercart's.

I am a programmer, so if you encounter problems you are welcome to contact me for some support...

Regards,
Shushu

Comment: Hi Shushu, thanks very much for your answer and kind offer. If I run into difficulties I may be in touch. Ben

Comment: What would be the best way for me to contact you?

Answer (score 1):

This is late but I will just put in a solution for the next guy who searches for it.

If you want to integrate Paypal. There are many options in Drupal, ubercart http://drupal.org/project/ubercart is the best IMO as it is actively maintained. Paypals WPP and WPS comes under Ubercart's package, you will just need to configure the API credentials and other things.

If you are interested in recurring payments, there is a ubercart recurring subscriptions module too. http://drupal.org/project/uc_recurring

Answer (score 0):

Good luck if you use Ubercart, it's paypal support is extremely buggy  and no one has been able to fix it for over 6 months, despite paypal being one of the most popular payment methods online.  Know what you're getting into...

Comment: what kind of bugs do you think of? Have you reported them on the official Drupal Ubercart page? (http://drupal.org/project/issues/ubercart?categories=All) Since your comment, there are some PayPal-related issues they have already fixed...